# Why does df.sample and df.apply work differently in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe I wish to sample

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100,2)),columns=list('AB'))
```

If we have

```
s = df.sample(5)
print(s)
```

We get a frame of length 5 which suggests to me that it's the indexes that have been sampled randomly, and then each row returned.

However, if I run

```
 t = df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(5))
 print(t)
```

I get a frame of length 10, with each column being sampled 5 times and the dataframe returning `NaN` in the cells that don't have an associated sample. Why is the behaviour of these two functions different? I would expect them to be the same?

It appears that `df.sample(5)` is equivalent to

```
 df.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x,5))
```

So now if I group the dataframe.

```
g = df.groupby('A')
```

then `g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(2))` gives me what I want (a random sample of 2 from each group) but applying the same equivalence as before

```
 g.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x,2))
```

give me a `ValueError`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sample` by default will use the random seed at the time it's called (or a random one if it's not specified).

When you do `df.sample(5)` you're taking 5 random rows based on a single seed. However, when you do `t = df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(5))` a new seed is generated for each call of `.sample` (eg, a different one for each column) and the result will be N rows representing the number of unique indices that were sampled (likely to be 10 in your example but could be less).

You can force all calls to use the same random sequences by specifying the `random_state` argument to sample, eg:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(5, random_state=42))
```

Which gives you:

```
    A  B
83  8  3
53  7  3
70  7  2
45  3  8
44  1  1
```

Which is the same as what `df.sample(5, random_state=42)` gives you.

Comment: What I am confused about in the [.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) documentation is the comment: 'Objects passed to functions are Series objects having index either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the columns (axis=1).' So if I set `axis = 0` (which is default) why is it passing `.sample` to each column, and not just the index once? As in there should only be a single call of `.sample` on the index?

Comment: @MHorsley the `.apply` is called for each `column`... so you're effectivently doing: `for colname in df.columns: whatever = df[colname].sample(5)` and each `sample` call uses a different seed... So even though you're dealing with the same index, you're taking different indices from it each time per column.

Comment: I get it, makes sense further down when it says: '0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column
1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row'.  I find it very misleading to say that 'columns' applies to each 'row' and index applies to each column!